# Injectivity/Surjectivity of $F_A :=\frac{d}{dt} +A(t) $ for a hyperbolic path of matrices $A(t)$ on $H^1 $

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, index-theory

I am looking for a reference to the following problem:
Given a hyperbolic (no purely imaginary eigenvalues), continuous path of matrices $A(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with hyperolic limits at $\pm \infty $.
Under which assumptions (on A(t)) is the operator $F_A :=\frac{d}{dt} +A(t) :H^1 (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^m )\to L^2 (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^m )$ injective, resp. surjective?

Answer (score 6):

It is straightforward to see that if the path is constant then hyperbolicity is the equivalent to the invertibility of the operator for example via the Fourier transform (see Atiyah Patodi Singer *(Spectral Asymmetry and Riemann Geometry I)* for example).
It is then straightforward to see that if the $A(t)$ is asymptotically hyperbolic then the operator is Fredholm by a parametrix patching argument.
There is then a well-defined index problem.  The index is then equal to the spectral flow of the family $A(t)$, namely the intersection number of the spectrum with the imaginary axis.  This can be easily proved using the homotopy invariance
of the index and reducing to the case where the $A(t)$ are simultaneously diagonalizable with diagonal entries being either constant or $\pm\tanh(t)$.  This can be solved explicitly with kernel or cokernel $\text{sech}(t)$ depending on the sign.

Back to your problem, the sign of the index provides an obstruction to the operator being injective or subject but not a complete one.  For example if $A(t)$
is direct sum of two matrix paths $A_-(t)$ and $A_+(t)$ of spectral flow $-n$ and $n$ respectively, then the corresponding operator has kernel and cokernel of dimension at least $n$ but the total operator has index $0$.  On the other hand, in the one-dimensional case it seems straightforward to see that it is a complete obstruction. Writing $\lambda(t)=a_{11}(t)$ the hyperbolicity assumption means that $a(t)$ converges at $\pm\infty$ to constants $a_\pm$ of the same sign.   An element of the kernel has the form:
$$
f(t)=c+\exp[-\int_0^t \lambda(s)ds]
$$
Regardless of how you choose the constant, $f(t)$ is exponentially growing at 
one end or the other. A similar argument applies to the cokernel.